# How to update data in Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android application I am using sqlite database. I use the following code to update data but the data is not updated.

```
public int setCurrentLevel(int level)
{
  //update table level set currentlevel = level;
  int slevel = level;
  Log.d("QUIZ APP", "inside on setcreatelevel is "+slevel);
  ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
  args.put("currentlevel", slevel);

  return db.update("level", args, "currentlevel" + ">=" + slevel, null);
}
```

Comment: please post the db adapter class also

Comment: public int setCurrentLevel(int level)
{
    //update table level set currentlevel = level;
    int slevel = level;
    Log.d("QUIZ APP", "inside on setcreatelevel is "+slevel);
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put("currentlevel", slevel);
    return db.update("level", args, 
                     "currentlevel" + ">=" + slevel, null)>0;

}

Comment: Use `ContentValues` for update. [Have a look at this blog and use their example app](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android)

Comment: does the table have a default value? it needs to have atleast a single  value where the `currentlevel>= slevel`.

Comment: In log it returns the slevel value. Database remains same as default value.

Comment: it should actually return the number of updated rows and not the slevel value. Please check the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
db.update("level",args,"currentlevel>= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(level) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this kind of code inside your function

```
public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String isbn,
String title, String publisher)
{
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(KEY_ISBN, isbn);
args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
args.put(KEY_PUBLISHER, publisher);
return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args,
KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Comment: I have created the table sqlite manager tool, will it be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    public int setCurrentLevel(int level)
   {
            //update table level set currentlevel = level;
            int slevel = level;
            Log.d("QUIZ APP", "inside on setcreatelevel is "+slevel);
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put("currentlevel", slevel);
             return db.update("level", args, 
                 "currentlevel" + ">=" + slevel, null)>0;

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query......... also mention some condition on which you want to fire this update

```
      db.execSQL("UPDATE "+tableName+" SET "+columnNameValue+" WHERE "+condition+"");
```

your query will look something like:

```
    db.execSQL("UPDATE level SET currentlevel="+slevel +" WHERE currentlevel \\>=" + slevel+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Field", value);
db.update("Table", cv, "Field='value'", null);
```